# regex match first occurrence in file

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to insert new object to `feLinks` array therefore I'm trying to target closing array tag `];` so I can append an object to the array.

I'm trying to match the first occurrence of `];` so I could inject a new object

I do know about lazy quantifier, but haven't been able to make it work.

```
var fedLinks = [{
    Name:" Test",
    data:'value',
    tag:"first"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    Name:"Dashboard",
    data:fedLinks
}];
```

Here is what I have tried

```
];.+?
```

But it returns no match

Comment: I'm trying to insert new object to `feLinks` array therefore I'm trying to target closing array tag `];` so I can append an object to the array.

Comment: You should put that in the actual question, not as a comment. Also, why do you have the `.+?` part; `sed` works if the regex matches only part of the line?

Comment: @Deano, show the desired result and specify your OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use awk with literal strings for robustness, portability, and clarity (none of which you can have with a sed solution):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{ add=(NR>1 ? add ORS : "") $0; next }
    s=index($0,"];") { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) add substr($0,s); add="" }
1' add.txt test.txt
```

The above reads the new record as a literal string from the file "add.txt" then inserts that just before the literal string "];" appears in "test.txt" and prints the result, again as a literal string. That way you don't have to worry about escape characters or regexp metacharacters  or backreferences or anything else in either input file - everything will be reproduced exactly as you typed it. It will also work as-is with any awk on any UNIX box.

For example (borrowing @Weike's sample added text):

```
$ cat test.txt
var fedLinks = [{
    name: "test1",
    data: "value1",
    tag: "first"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: fedLinks
}];
```

.

```
$ cat add.txt
,{
    name: "test2",
    data: "value2",
    tag: "second"
}
```

.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{add=(NR>1 ? add ORS : "") $0; next} s=index($0,"];"){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) add substr($0,s); add=""} 1' add.txt test.txt
var fedLinks = [{
    name: "test1",
    data: "value1",
    tag: "first"
},{
    name: "test2",
    data: "value2",
    tag: "second"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: fedLinks
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

```
$ sed -nr ':start;/\];/!{p;n;bstart};SUBSTITUTE;:end;p;n;bend'
```

Explains:

1. `:start;/\];/!{p;n;bstart}`: use a loop to print the line what it is util matching the first line containing `\];`.
2. use SUBSTITUTE to insert a new object to first array.
3. `:end;p;n;bend`: use a new `loop` to print the lines after the with the first `];`.

Here, I'll use `s` command to `substitute` the `null char` between `}` & `]` with your new `object`:

```
s/(})(])/\1,{\n    name: "test2",\n    data: "value2",\n    tag: "second"\n}\2/
```

for example:

```
$ cat test.txt 
var fedLinks = [{
    name: "test1",
    data: "value1",
    tag: "first"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: fedLinks
}];
```

we want to add another `object` to `fedLinks` array:

```
$ sed -nr ':start;/\];/!{p;n;bstart};s/(\})(\])/\1,{\n    name: "test2",\n    data: "value2",\n    tag: "second"\n}\2/;:end;p;n;bend' test.txt
var fedLinks = [{
    name: "test1",
    data: "value1",
    tag: "first"
},{
    name: "test2",
    data: "value2",
    tag: "second"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: fedLinks
}];
```

### Solution 2:

We can change the way of thinking how to achieve functional. Instead of finding the `first }];`, we can find `complete feLinks array block`, then do your `insert` operations.

```
$ sed -r '/fedLinks.*\[\{/!bend;:loop;N;/\}\]/{SUBSTITUTE;bend};bloop;:end'
```

Explains:

1. `fedLinks.*\[\{`: find the beginning of the `array` which you want to insert a new object; or just jump to label `end` to read next line from stream.
2. `:loop`: set a label `loop` to read the `remaining` lines which belong to the `fedLinks` array.
3. `N;...;bloop`: append `\n` and next line from stream into `pattern space` util matching the `\}\]`, which means the end of `fedLinks` array.
4. `/\}\]/{SUBSTITUTE;bend};bloop`: deal with the `fedLinks` array when fetching all lines belonged to the `fedLinks` array and then jump to label `end`.

for example:

```
$ sed -r '/fedLinks.*\[\{/!bend;:loop;N;/\}\]/{s/(})(])/\1,{\n    name: "test2",\n    data: "value2",\n    tag: "second"\n}\2/;bend};bloop;:end' test.txt
var fedLinks = [{
    name: "test1",
    data: "value1",
    tag: "first"
},{
    name: "test2",
    data: "value2",
    tag: "second"
}];

var fedSet = [
{
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: fedLinks
}];
```

Comment: Among other issues, that will fail given given various values of the input (e.g. try changing `data: `value2"` to `data: "value2 & value3"`), requires duplicating the search regexp, and will only work in GNU sed. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk.